# How can I call the result of a function to use later?

Tags: python

I am taking a beginners course in python and am having some trouble. If I have a function e.g. (below) how can I call the result to use later. I know there are other ways to do this but my teacher wants us to understand how to use functions better. Thank you for any help!

```
def twodp(x):
    (x)= "%.2f" % (x)


twodp(mean_male_temp)
```

Now all the information required can be printed

```
print ("The average male temperature is:", (twodp(mean_male_temp)),"°F")
```

When I do this I get the following;

```
The average male temperature is: None °F
```

FWI the function works for me (i.e. it does round the average temperature to 2 dp).

Comment: you aren't returning anything.  you need a `return` statement and I think you are trying to return x in this case.

Comment: I think you need to read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your value:

```
def twodp(x):
    x = "%.2f" % (x,)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value from a function you have to use keyword `return`:

```
def twodp(x):
    return "%.2f" % (x)
```

There're countless resources on learning Python for beginners, eg.: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/

Or about returning values from functions for example: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#returned-function-values